# Saving a file in a servlet application on tomcat, how to figure out root of application?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm just testing out saving to a file from a servlet, and I want this to work regarding of where I host this application.

There is no security issue with the file being viewable from the web at this time.

Is there a way I can figure out the current running folder of the application, or could I store this information in my web.xml and retrieve it and store it in a static variable and then reference it in my applications servlet class?

I don't want to perform a lookup in a config file each time the web page renders, speed is very import for this silly little test I'm playing around with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ServletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

That said, you wouldn't look up a proper value in a file each time, you'd either specify it as an init-param, or load it in at startup and store it in the application context.

Comment: I have the most bear bone hello world servlet at the moment, how could I load it up at startup and store/retrieve from app context? thanks man!

Comment: @Blankman Could do it in the init() method (IIRC), or just look up the init-param each time. Don't recall how at the moment, but a quick search for "servlet init param" should be all you need to get going :)

Comment: @Blankman That said, I'd be pretty cautious about saving files to the app's context; they could be deleted on a redeploy, and it's often not even possible if deploying a war file.

Comment: I'm not saving the file, i'm saving the path to where I want to save the file to, get it?

Comment: @Blankman Yes, but the way you worded your question it sounded like you wanted to save the file there, so I provided the information. Get it?

Comment: I said "just testing out saving to a file from a servlet", not sure what you got confused.  BTW, when I wrote 'get it' I didn't that to come across as being rude, I appreciate your guidance :)

Comment: @Blankman You need to save the file somewhere: you didn't say where you were saving it, you were asking how to get the root directory of the application, and you said you wanted it to work across all server environments. Sounds exactly like you want to save it to the app's context.